# how to select multiple image with UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Select Multiple Images (UIImagePickerController or Photos.app Share UI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291270/select-multiple-images-uiimagepickercontroller-or-photos-app-share-ui)

I'm a newbie in iPhone development,the site give me a lot of help. But now, I meet a trouble, I want to select more than one photo in photoalbum, but when I use the UIImagePickerController , I can get just one photo, could you tell me how to select more photos?  thank you.

best regards,

ofllm

Comment: The question is a lot like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291270/select-multiple-images-uiimagepickercontroller-or-photos-app-share-ui

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to create your own view controller that will list the movies you are currently selecting. Use UIImagePickerController to build up your list one image at a time. There is no multiple selection available in the UIImagePickerController view itself.

Comment: Can you explain me how to go about this ?

Answer (score 3):

this might help you:
http://www.icodeblog.com/cloning-uiimagepickercontroller-using-the-assets-library-framework/