# how to select multiple photos from photoalbum by programming

Tags: iphone

I want to select multiple photos from photoalum each time by programming,
could you tell me how to do .

thank you very much.

best regards,

ofllm

Comment: Do you have any  more information? Which language are you using? Objective C for iOS or is it a website for iPhones? Have you tried anything, we need more detail to provide a good answer. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select Multiple Images (UIImagePickerController or Photos.app Share UI)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291270/select-multiple-images-uiimagepickercontroller-or-photos-app-share-ui)

Answer (score 1):

seems it's impossible, please check here [Select Multiple Images (UIImagePickerController or Photos.app Share UI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291270/select-multiple-images-uiimagepickercontroller-or-photos-app-share-ui)

Answer (score 0):

[ELCImagePicker](https://github.com/elc/ELCImagePickerController) is a great way to accomplish this.