# Select multiple photos from camera roll in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there a way to allow users to select multiple photos at once from the camera roll like the WiFiPhoto app does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ELCImagePicker](https://github.com/elc/ELCImagePickerController) will accomplish this exactly.

Answer (score 0):

seems it's impossible, please check here 
[Select Multiple Images (UIImagePickerController or Photos.app Share UI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291270/select-multiple-images-uiimagepickercontroller-or-photos-app-share-ui)

Comment: Hi disorderdev,

Thanks for caring to reply. I somehow got that done. Not a straight forward way but here is how it goes..
Once you show the image picker, place a transparent view over that. as soon as the user clicks on an image, note down the position of the click and pass on the touch event so that the imagepickerDidFinishPicking method gets called. Save that image and place some checkmark kind of image over the selected image. You dismiss the picker only on clicking done button.