# Multiple photo select using UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone

How to select multiple photos from photo album using `UIImagePickerController` ?

Answer (score 0):

This has been discussed here:

[Select Multiple Images (UIImagePickerController or Photos.app Share UI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291270/select-multiple-images-uiimagepickercontroller-or-photos-app-share-ui)

And it looks like that at the moment, there is no way to do it using the public API... :(

Answer (score 0):

you can't select multiple photos with that control AFAIK.... the following link might help  you
http://www.icodeblog.com/cloning-uiimagepickercontroller-using-the-assets-library-framework/