# multiple UIImageViews with UIImagePickers

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I have 3 UIImageViews for which I want to load an image.
For 1 image this is not a problem, but how do I scale to 3?
The code below is what I have right now.

```
-(IBAction) getPhoto:(id) sender {
UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

}


- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];    
UIImage* image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
[my_image_1 setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

Comment: You want to load the same image on all 3 `UIImageView`s? If that's so then just do `setImage:forState:` for all your image views, not just for the first one.

Comment: I want to load 3 different images. So 3 buttons to load the images. - ErikS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362377/multiple-photo-select-uisng-uiimagepickercontroller) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291270/select-multiple-images-uiimagepickercontroller-or-photos-app-share-ui)? They seem to be pointing to this [resource](http://www.icodeblog.com/cloning-uiimagepickercontroller-using-the-assets-library-framework/).

**Edit**

Based on your comment, I suggest you declare an ivar `imageViewToSet` in your class and alter your methods in the problem as below,

```
-(IBAction) getPhoto:(id) sender {
    // Add code to identify the sender(button) via tags or outlets and set imageViewToSet to the mapped imageView through a switch or if statement.
    UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}


- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];    
    imageViewToSet.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
}
```

Comment: I did came across these links. I don't want to select multiple images at the same time. In the ViewController I have 3 images and 3 buttons to select the images. Can I somehow pass the 'sender' to the imagePickerController ?

Comment: Added an edit based on your comment. Does this suit what you need?