# How to select multi-images from UIImagePickercontrol in iPhone?

Tags: iphone

How to select a multi-Images from ImagePicker control at a time?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291270/select-multiple-images-uiimagepickercontroller-or-photos-app-share-ui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create your own ImagePicker. See this [ELCImagePicker](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/10/07/cloning-uiimagepickercontroller-using-the-assets-library-framework/)