# Uploading Multiple Image using UIImagePickerController in IPhone Application

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

i am working with an iOS application in which i want to select multiple images using UIImagepickercontroller and then upload it on DropBox.
i found in some places that by using UIImagepickercontroller we only select single image at once a time . i am using the below code  for selecting multiple images using UIImagepickercontroller with the help of UIPopovercontroller :

```
 UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString*) kUTTypeImage];
       // [self presentViewController: imagePicker animated:YES completion:NULL];

     popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
        [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 400.0, 300.0)inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

but when i run this application i only get a popup window and just select single image.
Is there any way by which i can select multiple images?
Please help me out.
Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select Multiple Images (UIImagePickerController or Photos.app Share UI)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291270/select-multiple-images-uiimagepickercontroller-or-photos-app-share-ui)

Answer (score 2):

There are so many third party classes which enables us to pick multiple images from asset library and all are listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20756899/how-to-select-multiple-images-from-uiimagepickercontroller).

I suggest you to use [ELCImagePickerController](https://github.com/B-Sides/ELCImagePickerController).

You may choose your option [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20756899/how-to-select-multiple-images-from-uiimagepickercontroller).

Comment: thank you for your assistance,but i already worked with the E:CImagePICKERController.My requirement is to use UIImagePickerController for multiple Selection.Do You have any idea about it??