# trying to learn how to load images from photo library to collection view

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to learn how to use  collections views and what I want to do is be able to access the photos in the photo library 
and put them in a collection view .

The problem i’m having is getting the photos to show up in the cell when I click them nothing shoes up in the cell. I’ not sure what I’m doing wrong. I’m pretty sure i’m missing something but I don’t know what."

```
 import UIKit
 import Photos

 class ViewController: UIViewController  , UICollectionViewDelegate , UICollectionViewDataSource , UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout , UIImagePickerControllerDelegate  , UINavigationControllerDelegate
{

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

@IBAction func addPhoto(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    let picker:UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    picker.mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .photoLibrary)!

    picker.delegate = self
    picker.allowsEditing = false
    self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)



}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
       let cell: ImageCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell




    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
 return   3
}


func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {



    if let pickedimage = (info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage){





    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)




}
```

Collectionview cell

```
import UIKit

 class ImageCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {


 @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!



func configurecell(image: UIImage){


    imageView.image = image





}
```

}

Comment: You can do this using an array of data, which holds the images data representation. Use `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`. Then you can access it using tags of the buttons

Answer (score 1):

For picking Multiple Images from `UIImagePicker` :- [Select Multiple Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291270/select-multiple-images-uiimagepickercontroller-or-photos-app-share-ui)

As for populating a CollectionView, Update or store your data in the datasource and call `update`.

```
import UIKit

import Photos


class ViewController: UIViewController  , UICollectionViewDelegate , UICollectionViewDataSource , UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout , UIImagePickerControllerDelegate  , UINavigationControllerDelegate

  {


  @IBOutlet weak var myCollectionView: UICollectionView!//Define separate collectionview outlet with a different name than any parameter in any of the function

  var imagesArray = [UIImage]()

  override func viewDidLoad(){
      super.viewDidLoad()
        myCollectionView.delegate = self
        myCollectionView.datasource = self
       }


  @IBAction func addPhoto(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    let picker:UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    picker.mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .photoLibrary)!

        picker.delegate = self
        picker.allowsEditing = false
            self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
         }


  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
   let cell: ImageCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell

      cell.configurecell(imagesArray[indexPath.row])

     return cell

  }


  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

      return imagesArray.count ?? 0

  }



  func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let pickedimage = (info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage){
        imagesArray = [pickedImage,pickedImage,pickedImage]//Will store three selected images in your array
           myCollectionView.reloadData()
   }
   dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
```